# Get Length of Bytes stored in a data column which stores binary data

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data column in my table that stores "image"(SQLDBType) type i.e . it has binary data.
I want to read the value of the above column in SQLDataReader through C#.
I used the function

```
dr.GetBytes(6,0,Data,0,length);
```

6 -> my column no.

0 -> start index from where to read

data -> buffer where i want to read

0-> index in buffer where i want to copy

length -> length of the data to be read.

now i want to get the length of the binary data in the datacolumn (here, i have used length variable above).

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another column to your query that uses the SQL [`DATALENGTH`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function. Read that column's value first, then allocate your buffer and use `GetBytes`.

By the way, you should be migrating away from [`image`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).

> **ntext** , **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use [nvarchar(max)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), [varchar(max)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx), and [varbinary(max)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) instead.

Comment: Great Info about the updates in the coming versions of MS SQl Server.

Answer (score 3):

You could let the database tell you that - eg

```
SELECT data, DATALENGTH(data) AS DataSize
FROM tableOfData
WHERE id = yourId
```